# Can't see meta tags on source code using Helmet

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags, react-helmet

I can't see my meta tags on my source code.

I see my tags only when I inspect my page on Elements . Is it enough to show meta tags in elements  to correctly register my page on search engines?

I'm using React Helmet without a server.

Home page:

```js
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet';

export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {

        return (     
            <div> 
                    <Helmet>
                        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                        <title>Home</title>
                        <link rel="canonical" href="https://somedomain.com/" />
                        <meta name="description" content="Description here ......." />
                    </Helmet>  
                    ......
```

My index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div id="root"></div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Output inspect Elements:

```html
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://somedomain.com/" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta charset="utf-8" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta name="description" content="Description here ......" data-react-helmet="true">
```

Output Source code:

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png"><link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest"><link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5"><head><link href="/static/css/2.69121389.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="/static/css/main.8a7e4572.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="root"></div><script>!function(e){function t(t){for(var n,i,l=t[0],f=t[1],a=t[2],c=0,s=[];c<l.length;c++)i=l[c],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,i)&&o[i]&&s.push(o[i][0]),o[i]=0;for(n in f)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(f,n)&&(e[n]=f[n]);for(p&&p(t);s.length;)s.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,a||[]),r()}function r(){for(var e,t=0;t<u.length;t++){for(var r=u[t],n=!0,l=1;l<r.length;l++){var f=r[l];0!==o[f]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(t--,1),e=i(i.s=r[0]))}return e}var n={},o={1:0},u=[];function i(t){if(n[t])return n[t].exports;var r=n[t]={i:t,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[t].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,i),r.l=!0,r.exports}i.m=e,i.c=n,i.d=function(e,t,r){i.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},i.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},i.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=i(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var r=Object.create(null);if(i.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)i.d(r,n,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,n));return r},i.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return i.d(t,"a",t),t},i.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},i.p="/";var l=this["webpackJsonpmy-website"]=this["webpackJsonpmy-website"]||[],f=l.push.bind(l);l.push=t,l=l.slice();for(var a=0;a<l.length;a++)t(l[a]);var p=f;r()}([])</script><script src="/static/js/2.c77f8540.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.69bc3bde.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: You're not using SSR? Without SSR some of the benefits are lost on crawlers that don't run JS.

Comment: What can I use in this case?

Comment: SSR or hardcode it, or hope it's a crawler that runs JS.

Comment: Yes, I decide to use SSR, and I solved the problems. Thanks, for an answer.

Comment: How did you solve it?